# Difference between Sybase and SQL Server distinct convert(char(32), field)

Tags: sql-server, sybase

I'm seeing an odd behavior in Sybase when I run a query that has `select DISTINCT CONVERT(CHAR(32), field) from mytable` in a select query.

In Sybase and SQL Server a select query with `CONVERT(CHAR(32), field)` adds the appropriate trailing padding for values less than 32 characters as expected.

However adding a distinct clause to the query as such `DISTINCT CONVERT(CHAR(32), field)` results in trailing padding in SQL Server as expected however Sybase trims all trailing spaces when a `DISTINCT` clause is added.

Does anyone have an explanation of the Sybase behavior?

Comment: I can't provide a direct answer as I haven't used Sybase for 25 years but it seems the combination of `DISTINCT` and `CONVERT` in Sybase behaves like Microsoft SQL Server `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF` option, trimming trailing spaces from `CHAR`.  You will get the same behavior with Microsoft SQL Server if you run the query from a session with `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF`. I don't know if this is documented behavior in Sybase.

Comment: I tried setting SET ANSI_PADDING OFF but the behavior is the same and SQL Server adds to padding per the specs of char datatype

Comment: Hmm. This is the script I ran under SQL Server 2019, which returned the trimmed column length of 1: `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;
CREATE TABLE #a (field varchar(10));
INSERT INTO #a VALUES('a');
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(char(32),field) AS field INTO #b FROM #a;
SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(field)) FROM #b;
DROP TABLE #a, #b;`. It returned 32 with `SET ANSI_PADDING ON;`.